# html5 audio play issue with firefox/chrome

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, audio

I have a music player which is html5 based.  the link is http://playhotmusic.com/beatstore/vip1/mobile/  well the problem is it works fine on certain Android Phones (Galaxy s3) but not on the Note 4.  Not just that in firefox and chrome this player doesnt work correctly.  An example is I can click the first song and it will play, if I change the song it doesnt change its still playing the first song.  I'm seeing if anyone can please help me solve the issue with this.  I've spent so much time trying to figure it out and I can't.  Any ideas ?

Comment: If you can paste in your code, I may be able to help you with this.

Comment: its pretty long but you can download the index file here...please let me know if you need anything more  http://www.playhotmusic.com/beatstore/vip1/mobile/index.html.zip @YuujinLee  Thanks !